# how to use C++ redistributable in podman containers?

Tags: c#, c++, docker, containers, podman

Plan to run a combined c# and cpp application in a podman container. for cpp it depends with some toolkit and c++ distributable. How do i create a image with dependencies since podman containers are linux based? also like to know can i use c++ dependencies by coping lib dll directly into image ?

some sample are there to use C++ distributable in windows containers(Docker).

Comment: Just to clarify: you are talking about creating _linux_ containers? What compiler did you use for the c++ part?

Comment: @Botje, actually our startup application is C# and using cpp project by dllimport. so currently not using any compiler for cpp and using dotnet base image and adding cpp references ( toolkit lib ,dll) into c# startup folder same as current desktop application. is it wrong way to use this ?

Comment: On linux the c++ standard library tends to be a package you can install globally (libstdc++ for GCC, libc++ for clang) so you do not need to mess with "redistributables".

Comment: https://dockerlabs.collabnix.com/beginners/dockerfile/ADD-command.html

Comment: Thanks Botje and Alan.. will check and update.. :-)